# Getting not found on config well known error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am having a very strange issue with swagger its now saying my controller cannot be found and its giving me the following error. I am using .net core 3.1

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44396/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
>    ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:44396/.well-known/openid-configuration'. HttpResponseMessage: 'StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
>   {
>     Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>     Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>     X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>     Date: Sat, 23 May 2020 01:17:55 GMT
>   }', HttpResponseMessage.Content: ''.

The Following is my configuration for JWT.

```
 public static class AddTokenAuthentications {
    public static IServiceCollection AddTokenAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) {
        var secret = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("SecretKey").Value;
        var keySecret = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(secret);

        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keySecret.ToString());
        services.AddAuthentication(x => {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
               .AddJwtBearer(x => {

                   {
                       x.Audience = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("Audience").Value;
                       x.Authority = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("Authority").Value;


                       x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                       x.SaveToken = true;
                       x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                           IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                           ValidateIssuer = false,
                           ValidateAudience = false
                       };
                   }
               });

        return services;
    }
  }
```

But in my app settings json i save the to authority and the audience. Can someone please tell me what might be wrong.

This is my curl command that swagger is sending.

> curl -X GET "https://localhost:44396/api/BmiInformations" -H "accept:
>   text/plain" -H "Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTAxOTg0NTMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0Mzk2LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0Mzk2LyJ9.FdTk9D7m0mWhIKCgA82FHfb41cwqjmaqADtPgVOqtWs"

```
"JwtToken": {
  "SecretKey": "********************************",
  "Issuer": "https://localhost:44396/",
  "expirationInMinutes": "2",
  "Authority": "https://localhost:44396/",
  "Audience": "https://localhost:44396/"
},
```

**Edit 2**
Ok SO I dont need to set this

```
             x.Audience = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("Audience").Value;
             x.Authority = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("Authority").Value;
```

But when I remove it am back to square one of invalid signautre

Comment: Who's the authority? IdentityServer?

Comment: I dont no yes I am using Identy with JWT

Comment: Have you tried with http version of audience and authority values?

Comment: ah got u u mean its cause I dont have an https installed on local client this would work then on a live url @MeruzhHovhannisyan